# how to keep all floated images in one line?

Tags: css

```
<div id="divT">
<img class="divTimg" src="divT/00.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="divTimg" src="divT/01.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="divTimg" src="divT/02.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="divTimg" src="divT/03.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="divTimg" src="divT/04.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="divTimg" src="divT/05.jpg" alt="img">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#divT{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.divTimg{
    float:left;
    width:17%;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-right:2px ridge gold;
}
```

`05.jpg` is placed in a new line, bellow the rest of images, but I need to keep them all in one line, and if there is no space enough - the last image should be visible partly.

I tried with various values of `overflow-x` for the parrent div, but without success.

Comment: Why are you using `float` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the 'scrolling off to the side effect' you need to create a wrapper element, that contains a much wider element that then contains your images. This then allows you to shrink or grow the visible section, while having the hidden content appear scrollable.

```
 <div class="scroll">
    <div class="scroll_wrapper">
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
        <img class="scroll_image" src="" />
    // images
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS

```
.scroll {
    width: 200px; // how much you want to see at once
    overflow: auto;
}

.scroll_wrapper {
    width: 600px; // this can be any number higher than the total width of the elements inside it
}

.scroll_image {
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 50px; // just to test the scrolling
}
```

The jsfiddle for this can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxL3h3qp/)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your image list with another wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="divT">
        <img class="divTimg" src="divT/00.jpg" alt="img">
        <img class="divTimg" src="divT/01.jpg" alt="img">
        <img class="divTimg" src="divT/02.jpg" alt="img">
        <img class="divTimg" src="divT/03.jpg" alt="img">
        <img class="divTimg" src="divT/04.jpg" alt="img">
        <img class="divTimg" src="divT/05.jpg" alt="omg">
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add some styles:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#divT {
    width:105%;
}
```